# Managing properly the error "Too few parameters. Expected 1" in Access

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

Currently I am coding a xml parser that retrieves data from an Access MDB database based on a list of items.

```
    <request>
      <item>deliveryDate</item>
      <item>senderName</item>
      <item>poundsWeight</item>
    </request>
```

Then I do something like this:

```
    SELECT ... items in list ... FROM tbl_name WHERE bla bla
```

Well, the parser is destined to be in a public location, and public may write bad some things (like the columns names).

The parser is supposed to read everything in the list, and do a bulk select against the database, even if some of the items does not exists in the table.

I am aware that the error "Too few parameters. Expected 1" is caused by a mistake on a column name in the select statement, but what I want is to find a way to manage gracefully the error without breaking the website on the front-end

Some points to take care:
1) The column names can vary in any time, that will be setted by the customer, so I just cannot set the names as constants.
2) The users also won't know which fields are available to retrieve, they just write the request list and wait for the parser result.

I am looking for a solution but seems out there is no enough info.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. If you want to validate column names, just obtain column names from Access first and check your column names.

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, I can think of 2 solutions: 1) prevent users from using column names that are not actually present in the table (surely that xml must be based on something); 2) if you can't do that, after reading the xml content, check for the existence of each column before you build and perform your actual query.

Comment: From what I can make out you are concerned about an attack such as SQL Injection. If you correctly parameterize and validate your variables then you should not have any problems with user supplied content. Bear in mind that for ASP Classic you also make sure that your 500 errors do not return useful information to the hacker.